# How to specify IPs for pods I want to health check?

Tags: kubernetes, health-check

I am trying to add health probes (HTTP probes) to my microservice. I use K8 and have 2 pods. I am following the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-http-request) but I can't understand how I can create health check requests for the specific pod.

Should I create the third pod using liveness/readiness image? How can I specify the IP of the pod I want to heath check?

Comment: `Http probe` is for the containers running some sort of server and have `/healthz` path configured in the server to return success. Why you need the IP ? Btw, what do you mean by "have 2 pods"

Comment: I created Ingress service and added health probes to it. It works perfectly fine on my local machine. The only thing I need to do is make a request e.g GET http://localhost:8081/actuator/health. The question is how can I transfer this to my cluster? I have 2 instances of this service (2 pods) and want to health check each of them. Should I create 3rd pod with HTTP probe or just add a container with health images to existing pods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to create any additional pod or image for this purpose. Kubernetes probes use some ways for checking containers (i.e. HTTP request, TCP check). If we talk about the below snippet sample,  kubelet itself send HTTP request to the respective port /healtz path under certain conditions (such as periodSeconds or initialDelaySeconds)  which is described in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) and decide pod health whether running state or not with  considering  HTTP response code (such as HTTP 2xx OK or 5xx server error). Basically if kubelet receive success reponse code it decide pod is running state or if it gets 5xx response code pod never switch to the running state

```
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    scheme: HTTPS
    path: /healthz
    port: 8443
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 5
```

Comment: thank you, I get it, but the question is should I add this as the second container inside the pod?

Comment: No, as I said kubelet handle the whole healthcheck process including sending HTTP request to the container (not the pod) and evaluate the response. You should not do anything additional, just specify probes in kubernetes manifest.

Comment: ok, I get it, thank you!

Comment: If you find what you are looking for , please vote the answer @MarcinGemra